# Was it that easy to become a vice President at Dunder Mifflin?

Tags: the-office

Sure, Ryan from *The Office* went to Business School. But he had absolutely no prior professional or corporate experience. He was a temp in the Scranton branch, exactly how did he end up in New York to take over Jan's Position as Vice President of the company?

Comment: AFAIK, she wasn't the VP of the entire *company*, just of regional sales.

Comment: It's been a few years since I watched The Office, but didn't he interview for it with a few other people (including Michael)? The fact that he was unqualified is the entire point; *that's the joke*. In the real world, in plenty of offices, there are totally unqualified people in relatively high level positions they have no business being in. They don't generally jump from temp to VP (of anything), but The Office is all about taking general office working life tropes to the extreme.

Comment: [" She is the Vice President ***of Northeast Sales***"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Levinson).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Ryan had a masters of business administration.  That's pretty well educated and probably does qualify him for that position.

Comment: @JMac - I don't think that's a particularly valid claim. He has a MBA in the show, snags that position then proves fairly quickly he has no idea what he's doing and ends up way back down at the bottom again.

Comment: @KaiQing I think that has more to do with bad staff picks than lack of qualification.  A MBA really would be a good way to qualify for high managerial roles like that.  His addiction to cocaine and the fast life weren’t really compatible though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My theory is yes, it is so easy to become vice president of Dunder Mifflin. That's most likely why they were bought out by Sabre. It's because all of the guys in the New York branch were idiots and had no clue what they were doing and didn't care, most likely because it's a paper company, and who cares about paper?

Comment: This is somewhat confirmed when Michael talks to David Wallace when it is revealed that the company is going under, when David admits that their remote offices like Scranton are the only profitable part of Dunder Mifflin. There are many indications that the company is mismanaged on higher levels.